# how to do this operation in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have a data frame that contains country column. Unfortunately the country names characters are all capitalized and I need them to be ISO3166_1_Alpha_3
as an example United States of America is going to be U.S.A 
United Kingdom is going to be U.K and so on.

Fortunately I found this data frame on the internet that contains 2 important columns the first is the country name and the second is the ISO3166_1_Alpha_3
you can find the data frame on this website
https://datahub.io/JohnSnowLabs/iso-3166-country-codes-itu-dialing-codes-iso-4217-currency-codes

So i wrote this code

```py
data_geo = pd.read_excel("tab0.xlsx")#this is the data frame that contains all the capitalized country name
country_iso = pd.read_csv(r"https://datahub.io/JohnSnowLabs/iso-3166-country-codes-itu-dialing-codes-iso-4217-currency-codes/r/iso-3166-country-codes-itu-dialing-codes-iso-4217-currency-codes-csv.csv",
                          usecols=['Official_Name_English', 'ISO3166_1_Alpha_3'])

s = pd.Series(data_geo.countery_name_e).str.lower().str.title()#this line make all the names characters small except the first character
y = pd.Series([])
```

Now i want to make a loop when a

```
s = Official_Name_English
```

I want to append

`country_iso[Official_Name_English].ISO3166_1_Alpha_3`

to the `Y` series. If country name isn't in this list append `NaN` 
this is 20 rows in s

```
['Diffrent Countries', 'Germany', 'Other Countries', 'Syria',
       'Jordan', 'Yemen', 'Sudan', 'Somalia', 'Australia',
       'Other Countries', 'Syria', 'Lebanon', 'Jordan', 'Yemen', 'Qatar',
       'Sudan', 'Ethiopia', 'Djibouti', 'Somalia', 'Botswana Land']
```

Do you know how can i make this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try `map`:

```
data_geo = pd.read_excel("tab0.xlsx")
country_iso = pd.read_csv(r"https://datahub.io/JohnSnowLabs/iso-3166-country-codes-itu-dialing-codes-iso-4217-currency-codes/r/iso-3166-country-codes-itu-dialing-codes-iso-4217-currency-codes-csv.csv",
                      usecols=['Official_Name_English', 'ISO3166_1_Alpha_3'])
s = pd.Series(data_geo.countery_name_e).str.lower().str.title()

mapper = (country_iso.drop_duplicates('Official_Name_English')
                     .dropna(subset=['Official_Name_English'])
                     .set_index('Official_Name_English')['ISO3166_1_Alpha_3'])
y = data_geo['countery_name_e'].map(mapper)
```

Comment: it returned this eror InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: Could be due to duplicates and/or NaNs in the `Official_Name_English` column. Try the edited answer now